# Updating autoconf on OSX Lion

Tags: osx-lion, updates, autoconf

New Mac user here (got it for work), so hopefully this is just me being stupid.

Anyway, I'm trying to update my autoconf, and it seems to be stuck...and I'm not sure why.
I am trying to update to Autoconf 2.65, however every time I run the installation I get:

```
autoconf -V 
autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.61
```

I downloaded a few different packages and ran through them as I would normally...

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

I'm the only user on the system...and I should be the computer admin as well.  Any thoughts?

My problem is that the software package I'm trying to install requires autoconf 2.61a-341 or better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, nobody?

Figured it out...the issue was that when calling ./configure, it was simply installing to the local directory and not the system.

What is required if you want to update the main autoconf is changing the path in the configure:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```